# How do I share the URL of my application with another application in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, microservices

I have two applications on Bluemix and I need to give the URL of one application to the other one.

```
$response = http_get("myOrdersApp12345.mybluemix.net/api");
```

Hard coding the URL in my source code seems like a bad idea... What if the url changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard coding the URL or any credentials in the source is bad practice. In Bluemix, you can pass these credentials to your application using the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. This is same environment variable that holds credentials for Bluemix services.

You are essentially creating your own service visible to your org and space by creating a **user-provided service**.

Create a new service that provides the url to consumers of this service:

```
$ cf cups myOrdersAppService -p "url"
url> myOrdersApp12345.mybluemix.net/api
Creating user provided service myOrdersApp in org **** / space ****
OK
```

And then binding this service to the application that wants this “url” information

```
$ cf bind-service myOtherApplication myOrdersAppService
```

myOtherApplication can how get the url by parsing the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. For example, in PHP:

```
$services = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
$services_json = json_decode($services, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($services_json["user-provided"]); $i++){
    if ($services_json["user-provided"][$i]["name"] == "myOrdersApp"){
        $ordersHost = $services_json["user-provided"][$i]["credentials"]["url"];
        $response = http_get($ordersHost);
    }
}
```

You can use this same method to share credentials of any external services (like databases). When using the microservice architecture, this feature becomes extremely useful.

```
$ cf cups myExternalDB -p "host, username, password"
host> 123.123.123.123
username> myusername
password> mypassw0rd
```

For more details, check out this doc: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html

Comment: But if the value does change, you would have to unbind/rebind your app from the user-provided service in order to see the changed value in VCAP_SERVICES, right? Or is there a way to get that to update dynamically? So if you're only setting one value like the URL in your question, would there really be any advantage to doing it this way rather than just using `cf set-env`?

Comment: Right. `cf uups` to update the service info, and then `cf unbind-service`, `cf bind-service` and `cf restage` the app. One advantage of cups instead of set-env...easy visualization of dependency mapping in the Bluemix console, especially when binding to multiple applications. Two, while not applicable for single value entires, you can get Liberty server.xml and client library auto-configuration support for external services.
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/service-plugins.md#user-provided-service-instances

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ram's suggestion to retrieve service parameters via `VCAP_SERVICES`, especially when it specifies information intrinsic to the binding of a service to your application like credentials. However, for more mundane configuration properties (e.g., what languages are supported and where are the translations located? What URL should be used for invoking this REST service?), traditional methods like passing them on the command line, retrieving them from a configuration file, or getting them from environment variables specified by the admin at deployment time are perfectly legitimate.

Pat Mueller's [Keeping secrets – how your cloud application should access credentials and other private data](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/14/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/) nicely summarizes the options and tradeoffs. Most importantly, he underscores the importance of **not** hardcoding sensitive information, especially given the likelihood that code will be stored in a repository where it's not readily evident who will have access, unlike a deployment script maintained by the system admin.